# Как сделать такую форму?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Как сделать такую форму?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Взято отсюда:

```
https://djinni.co/wish/
```

После вставки этого:

```
<input name="salary_min" id="salary_min" step="100" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input salary" value="1500" required="" type="number">
```

Получилось так. Но тут нету счётчика. как его сделать? Каким образом (скриптом) его обрабатывать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я вставил его просто так тут (опция Фрагмент кода), и счетчик тут есть. Мб у вас какие то стили прячут эту область

Comment: А как определить какие стили прячут?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При наведении и фокусе видны стрелочки:

```css
label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 4px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 2px;
}

input {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 24px;
  padding: 3px 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
}
```

```html
  <label for="salary_min">$</label>
  <input name="salary_min" id="salary_min" step="100" autocomplete="off" class="form-control input salary" value="1500" required="" type="number">
```

Причины, почему не отображается:

- Возможно и впрямь какие-то стили по-умолчанию мешают. Попробуйте открыть панель разработчика (в хроме f12) и посмотреть чтобы ничего не перекрывало стили инпута [скрин](http://prntscr.com/el2trz)
- Поддержка (возможно Ваш браузер не поддерживает `input[type="number"]`) [caniuse.com/#feat=input-number](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number)
- возможно стоит обязательно задать `min="N"` и `max="N"`

Comment: На странице только твой код . Но отображается всёравно неправильно

Comment: @codename0082016, возможно и впрямь какие-то стили по-умолчанию мешают. Попробуй открыть панель разработчика (в хроме f12) и посмотреть чтобы ничего не перекрывало стили инпута http://prntscr.com/el2trz

Comment: @codename0082016, + проверь поддержку (возможно твой браузер не поддерживает) http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number